# Undo/redo in AngularJS without undoing character by character

Tags: angularjs, undo, undo-redo

I am trying to implement an AngularJS page with text boxes with which the user enters stuff into. I want to be able to use undo/redo functionality on that page, but [angular-history](https://github.com/decipherinc/angular-history) only supports character by character undoing. Is there a way I can get undo/redo functionality with having to force the user to do it character by character?

Comment: I cover AngularJS Memento Factories here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45435927/1122851

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a (fairly new) [project](https://github.com/Blitzen/Angular-Chronicle) that handles this exact use case. After throwing it in my project and playing with it, it seems to be doing what I'd looked for.